# How can I improve this Makefile to optimize the usage of the SRC and BIN folders?

Tags: c, makefile

This is my first attempt at making a Makefile after having gone through several tutorials and the gnu make manual. The Makefile works and creates the .o, .a and .exe files in the BIN folder. However, I have have added src\ and bin\ prefixes to all files. I know there must be a better way of addressing folder issues while using Makefiles. Only problem is, I am unable to figure it out after hours of editing and trying out different things, based on the tutorials. I find GNU make manual too overwhelming at this stage of my learning curve.

I am using MinGW GCC toolchain on Windows 7. I have copied mingw32-make.exe to make.exe for the purpose of trying out the tutorials and exampples I have been going through.

I would really appreciate any help on the subject. Thank you.

My Makefile is as follows:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -c
BIN = bin/
LDFLAGS = -L$(BIN) -lmyLib

all: test.exe

test.exe: test.o libmyLib.a
    gcc bin\test.o -o bin\test.exe $(LDFLAGS)

test.o: src\test.c src\myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bin\test.o src\test.c

libmyLib.a: myLib.o
    ar rcs bin\libmyLib.a bin\myLib.o

myLib.o: src\test.c src\myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bin\myLib.o src\myLib.c

clean:
    del bin\*.* /Q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are some issues with your Makefile, even if it apparently works. When you write:

```
myLib.o: src\test.c src\myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bin\myLib.o src\myLib.c
```

you are lying to make:

1. You tell it that the result of the rule is `myLib.o` while it is `bin\myLib.o`, that is, a different file.
2. You tell make that `myLib.o` depends on `src\test.c` while it in fact depends on `src\myLib.c`.

Same with your other rules as in:

```
libmyLib.a: myLib.o
    ar rcs bin\libmyLib.a bin\myLib.o
```

You tell make that the rule shall be executed if `myLib.o` is newer than `libmyLib.a` while the real prerequisite is `bin\myLib.o` and the real target is `bin\libmyLib.a`.

By doing so you totally prevent make from doing what it is supposed to do: decide if a recipe must be executed or not, depending on the last modification times of target files and prerequisite files. Give it a try: run make twice and you'll see that it uselessly redoes what it did already. Never, never lie to make.

Second, you can improve your Makefile by using several advanced features like automatic (`$@`, `$<`, `$^`), standard (`LDLIBS`, `AR`, `ARFLAGS`) and regular (`BIN`, `SRC`) make variables. Here is an example of what you could try, after fixing the above mentioned issues and better using variables (plus adding the missing `-I` gcc option, and declaring `all` and `clean` as phony because these targets are not real files and we do not want to lie to make):

```
BIN = bin
SRC = src
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -c -I$(SRC)
LDFLAGS = -L$(BIN)
LDLIBS = -lmyLib
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = rcs

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)/test.exe

$(BIN)/test.exe: $(BIN)/test.o $(BIN)/libmyLib.a
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(BIN)/test.o: $(SRC)/test.c $(SRC)/myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BIN)/libmyLib.a: $(BIN)/myLib.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(BIN)/myLib.o: $(SRC)/myLib.c $(SRC)/myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    del $(BIN)\*.* /Q
```

Now, all non-phony targets and prerequisites are regular files, the ones that are really involved in the rules. Again, give it a try and you'll see that make rebuilds only what is out of date and thus needs to be rebuilt.

If you want to get rid of the `$(SRC)/` prefix you can use the `vpath` directive that tells make where to look for source files (I insist on **source**, many people try to use it for target files, this is not what it is intended for):

```
vpath %.h $(SRC)
vpath %.c $(SRC)
```

And then:

```
$(BIN)/test.o: test.c myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BIN)/myLib.o: myLib.c myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

> Note: you could also use the `VPATH` variable instead of the `vpath` directive.

Pattern rules are used to factor similar rules, like, for instance, your compilation rules that differ only by the names of the source file and object file:

```
$(BIN)/%.o: %.c myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

All in all:

```
BIN = bin
SRC = src
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -c -I$(SRC)
LDFLAGS = -L$(BIN)
LDLIBS = -lmyLib
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = rcs
vpath %.h $(SRC)
vpath %.c $(SRC)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)/test.exe

$(BIN)/test.exe: $(BIN)/test.o $(BIN)/libmyLib.a
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(BIN)/%.o: %.c myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BIN)/libmyLib.a: $(BIN)/myLib.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
    
clean:
    del $(BIN)\*.* /Q
```

Finally, if you really want to avoid the `$(BIN)/` prefix in your rules you will have to move to the `$(BIN)` directory and call make from there. You can leave the Makefile in the main directory and use the `-f ../Makefile` option, if you wish.

But of course this is less convenient that just typing `make [goals]` from the main directory. There are ways to let make test from where it has been called, and if it is not from the build directory, re-call itself with the `-C` and `-f` options such that it does its job from the build directory. But it is probably a bit too complicated if you are new to make.

If you are however interested have a look at [this post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/) that covers this topic (and more). If we simplify as much as possible what the post suggests and specialize it for your case, the final Makefile could be something like:

```
# here starts the black magic that makes it possible
.SUFFIXES:

BIN := bin
SRC := src

ifneq ($(notdir $(CURDIR)),$(BIN))

.PHONY: $(BIN) clean

$(BIN):
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $@ -f ../Makefile SRC=$(CURDIR)/$(SRC) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

Makefile: ;

% :: $(BIN) ; :

clean:
    del $(BIN)\*.* /Q

else
# here ends the black magic that makes it possible

# here starts the Makefile you would really like to write
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -O3 -Wall -c -I$(SRC)
LDFLAGS := -L.
LDLIBS  := -lmyLib
AR      := ar
ARFLAGS := rcs
vpath %.h $(SRC)
vpath %.c $(SRC)
.PHONY: all

all: test.exe

test.exe: test.o libmyLib.a
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c myLib.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

libmyLib.a: myLib.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
# here ends the Makefile you would really like to write

# a last bit of black magic
endif
```

The *Makefile you would really like to write* is what you would write if your source files and target files were all in the source directory. No prefixes any more; `vpath` takes care of the `$(SRC)/` prefix and `$(BIN)/` is useless because when this part of the Makefile is used we are already inside `$(BIN)`.

> Note: I know nothing about Windows and its various command line interfaces so there are probably some things to adapt (backslashes instead of slashes for instance).

Comment: I never tried, but can `vpath` also be used for sourcing object files? I suppose since Make knows nothing about different tools, it just works on recipes.

Comment: @thebusybee To know more abut this you can read, for instance [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/). It is about `VPATH` but is also valid for `vpath`.

Comment: Well, I hoped you just add `vpath %.o $(BIN)` ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee Nope, I will not, for the very good reasons explained in Paul's post ;-).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Wow! I have learnt more by going over your thorough reply than I have going over the various tutorials. It also helped me understand why my recipes were executing repeatedly. I now clearly understand the vpath directive. This is one of the places which had confused me, but now I can wrap my head around this. The last part of the suggestion seems too complicated for now. However, I will revisit this post and go through the article once I have a better grasp of Make.